# How can I comment out javascript that contains razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have this bit of javascript code in one of my razor views:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetNavigation","Account")', function (data) {
        $('#navigation').html(data);
    });
});
```

For debugging purposes I wanted to quickly disable this code so I thought I just add a pair of /* */ around the javascript code to make it a comment. I noticed that the VS 2013 intellisense did not mark the entire section as comment (wobbly red lines after the razor bit). So, instead I put a double slash at the beginning of each line. Now the intellisense doesn't complain anymore. But to my surprise when I run the code it turns out that  `@Url.Action("GetNavigation","Account")` still gets executed.

This does make sense on second thought as razor should be commented with @* *@ pairs. So to comment the whole section I need to do this:

```
// $(document).ready(function () {
//@*    $.post('@Url.Action("GetNavigation","Account")', function (data){*@
//          $('#navigation').html(data);
//      });
// });
```

While it makes sense it seems like overkill and looks clunky. Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: can't you do `@**@` around the whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @* and *@. These automatically create the valid characters.

Comment: I'll accept this one as answer. Of course I overlooked the most obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The intelisense complains but the comment works anyway. But any razor command inside a javascript comment will run. To avoid it, use the razor comment:

```
@{ /*
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("GetNavigation","Account")', function (data) {
            $('#navigation').html(data);
        });
    });
*/ }
```

That would prevent even the razor commands to run.

Comment: This works, but I'll accept @greenhorn 's answer as the /* */ do not seem to be required.

Comment: @Hintham ok. His answer is better for sure. I didn't know `@*` and `*@` indeed.